# How do I get an old version of Meteor?

Tags: deployment, meteor, downgrade

I deployed my app on my own server using Meteor v0.4.2 (I'm not sure that's the exact version number, but it's the latest pre-0.5.0).

Then, I made the mistake of upgrading to Meteor 0.5.2 locally and now don't know how to get 0.4.2 back in order to deploy to the server.

I tried deploying with version 0.5.2 but there's a strange bug that rears its head on the server.

Comment: What OS? What deployment system?

Answer (score 1):

You can run Meteor directly from a git checkout, so it should be possible to clone from the [meteor trunk](http://github.com/meteor/meteor), then checkout the [0.4.2 tag](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/v0.4.2) and run meteor that way.

Steps to do this are outlined in the readme at the root of the repo.